# libsvm file in scala mlib will not open

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I am getting the following error when loading a libsvm file using scala's mlib package:

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: requirement failed: 
indices should be one-based and in ascending order; found current=-1, 
previous=-1; line="0.0 0:1 60:1 80:3 144:2 270:1"
```

The formatting of the libsvm seems correct.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

libsvm files require that columns (i.e features/variables) start with the index 1, not 0.

So the problematic line should have been:

0.0 1:1 61:1 81:3 145:2 271:1